# How tuples are compared in python heap

Tags: python, heap

I'm really confused about tuple comparison in python heap when I was trying the following code

```
def topKFrequent(nums: List[int], k: int) -> List[int]:
    count = collections.Counter(nums)
    print(count)
    heap = []
    for key, val in count.items():
        if len(heap) >= k:
            if val > heap[0][0]:
                heapq.heapreplace(heap, (val, key))
        else:
        
            heapq.heappush(heap, (val, key))
    print(heap)
    return [item[1] for item in heap]
```

For example, the input nums is ["the","day","is","sunny","the","the","the","sunny","is","is"] and k = 3. The heap printed in the code is

```
[(2, 'sunny'), (4, 'the'), (3, 'is')]
```

But I think (4, 'the') > (3, 'is') since 4 > 3. Please help me solving this problem, thanks.

Comment: It's a heap, not a sorted list.

Comment: @user2357112 So only the smallest value will be on the top, but the rest part is not in order?

Comment: Can you link the Problem description or elaborate it?  Is this Leetcode's?  ```(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> List[int]``` should tne nums also contain integer?

Comment: Would be helpful to see the output of `count`, please.  Using simply a brain-debugger, it *appears* that given this line `if len(heap) >= k:`, the `heapreplace` statement is only running once, and possibly lending to the confusion.

Comment: Looks like a min heap. If so, your assumption about 4 > 3 is incorrect. You would compare child to parent not child to child.

Answer (score 1):

> But I think (4, 'the') > (3, 'is') since 4 > 3.

Yes, that is true, but these are *siblings* in the binary heap tree, and that means their value can compare either way. Heaps are not sorted lists. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap):

> the key stored in each node is either greater than or equal to (≥) or less than or equal to (≤) the keys in the node's children

As the two nodes you have mentioned here are not eachother's children, this rule does not apply to them.

A heap guarantees that its top (first) element has the least value, but there is no guarantee that the left child of that root element (at index 1) is the second-least value. That second-least value may sit in the root's right child (at index 2).

However, a heap *does* guarantee that when you pop elements from it (`heappop`), they will come out in sorted order.